# Google Maps API JavaScript Function Initialize

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I am working on a C# program that utilizes the Google Maps API. Everything works well but one of the issues I am facing is when the function is initializing. The function is called:

```
<script>
function initMap() {...}
</script>
```

The way it is called and run is through the Source File:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

These two snippets are in the same order as in the code.

I am trying to call the function and execute it through a button click.

Additional Snippets:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Crime_Maps.MainPage" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens/doesn't happen? What errors do you see in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)? Are you certain the function is not being called (vs. just not doing what you expect)?

Comment: What happens on the Debug console when I try to call from a button click and exclude the Source Call, The Google Maps URL above, (excluded because it will run normally if I do include it), is it will throw an error. The error refers to the object "google" in the snippit below:       var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;